# Условный оператор if 123

Tags: python, условия

У меня есть переменная:

```py
a = input()
```

Мне нужно, чтобы если ползователь введет `"hello"` или `"Привет"` исполнялся код:

```py
print("Привет")
```

как сделать это одним условием?

Answer (score 7):

```
a = input()
if a.lower() in ('hello', 'привет'):
    print("Привет")
```

Comment: один лишь код без пояснений — это всё-таки не самый лучший вариант ответа.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin он слишком элементарный. За пояснениями кода такого уровня лучше обращаться к учебнику.

Comment: итемнеменее® [Постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. Изложите свои предложения. Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)